# What's a simple way to convert between an am/pm time to 24 hour time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I've been playing with jquery and I've run myself into a time problem. I've got 3 time input select boxes, one for hours, one for minutes, and one for the Meridian. I need to convert this time into a 24 hour string format and then stick it into a hidden input.

```
var time = "";
time += $("#EventCloseTimeHour option:selected").text();
time += ":" + $("#EventCloseTimeMin option:selected").text() + ":00";
time += " " + $("#EventCloseTimeMeridian option:selected").text();

$("#ConditionValue").val(time);
```

This gives me "1:30:00 pm" where I need "13:30:00". Any quick javascript time tips?

Comment: I have to add I recently found out about datejs and it's amazing - you should think if you want to include an entire date library for a single problem (like above) but I do a lot of date math so it's more then useful. http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example of [tj111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12605/) suggestion:

```
$("#ConditionValue").val(
    (
        new Date(
            "01/01/2000 " + 
            $("#EventCloseTimeHour option:selected").text() +
            $("#EventCloseTimeMin option:selected").text() + ":00" +
            " " +
            $("#EventCloseTimeMeridian option:selected").text()
        )
    ).toTimeString().slice(0,8))
;
```

Or you can use:

```
hour = hour %12 + (meridian === "AM"? 0 : 12);
hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
```

Comment: I like yours the best so far but I get invalid date out of "toTimeString" and then It slices it up to just say "Invalid ". This is firefox with firebug, but it doesn't work in chrome either. I don't think the date object takes meridians

Comment: Check if you get the right values from the jquerys... If the input is invalid you get an invalid output.

Comment: @some—please don't recommend parsing with the built-in parser, it's implementation dependent and very error prone, per [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Also, [*toTimeString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.totimestring) is implementation dependent and may not return the required value.

Comment: Sure @RobG. Do you know where I can find a flux capacitor for my time machine, so that I can go back in time to February 2009 ?

Comment: @RobG, I know there is, but... this question was asked almost 8.5 years ago, with no activity until a bot updated the links from http to https about a month ago. I made this answer community wiki, since it was just an example of the method that tj111 suggested. I also show how to calculate the hour without using the date-object.Since it is accepted the person who asked the question was satisfied. Feel free to update this answer if it bothers you that much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the native [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) methods.

Comment: Is there a way to input the Meridian (am/pm)?

Comment: If you use the Date.parse method, it accepts AM/PM in the string (but requires a full date in front of it).

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with date parse - I keep getting invalid date format

Comment: Try with Date.parse("01/01/2001 12:00 PM"); (There needs to be a space between time time and AM/PM and the date has to be in the format shown)

Comment: @some—please don't recommend parsing with the built-in parser, it's implementation dependent and very error prone, per [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: @RobG You are correct that this would be better as a comment when using the current standard of Stackoverflow. But the site was different 8.5 years ago. It is also possible that tj111 didn't have enough reputation to post a comment back then.

Comment: @some—this answer has been linked as a duplicated, so it's not just about the OP. Maybe tj111 has left the building. :-/

Comment: Not as active on the answering side, but I still end up here all the time.  This was during the alpha or beta days of SO and the standards were a little different back then.  I agree it doesn't meet modern standards for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var time = "";
var hour = Number($("#EventCloseTimeHour option:selected").text())%12 + ($("#EventCloseTimeMeridian option:selected").text() == 'PM'?12:0)) ;


time +=("00"+String(hour)).slice(-2)+":"+ $("#EventCloseTimeMin option:selected").text();
```

The key to this solution is using the conditional operator "a?b:c" which translates to "if  a then b else c"

Comment: Still breaks with 12:xx AM. You always has to mod the time with 12, and then you add 12 if its PM.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with a few people's answers.

```
var time = "";
var hour = Number($("#EventCloseTimeHour option:selected").text());
if($("#EventCloseTimeMeridian option:selected").text() == 'PM'){
    hour = String((hour%12) + 12);
}
hour = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour;
time +=hour+":"+ $("#EventCloseTimeMin option:selected").text() + ":00";
```

Comment: Hours below 10 should be zeropadded. In 24h mode there are always two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a plain JS answer, the following will format the time based on the length of the initial string. If h:mm returns HH:mm, if h:mm:ss returns HH:mm:ss.

If HH:mm:ss is always required, it's simple to add default seconds of ":00" if not present in initial string.

```js
// Change time in h:mm:ss ap to  HH:mm:ss time
// If time missing seconds, returns HH:mm
function timeToHHmm(time) {
  var nums = time.match(/\d+/g);
  var am   = /am/i.test(time);
  nums[0] = ('0' + ((nums[0]%12) + (am? 0 : 12))).slice(-2);
  // If HH:mm:ss required, use following line instead of last
  // return nums.join(':') + (nums.length == 2? ':00' : '');
  return nums.join(':');
}

// Some tests
['2:45am',     // hh:mm only
 '5:15:45pm',  // hh:mm:ss
 '5:15:45 pm', // space before am/pm
 '05:15:45 pm',// leading zero on hour
 '12:02am',
 '12:02 pm',
 '12:02:00am'
 ].forEach(function(time) {
  console.log(time + ' => ' + timeToHHmm(time));
});
```