# Informix create procedure failure

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Informix (via `isql` as user informix), but I keep getting a 201 error, even on the simplest of procedures.  Here is the test procedure I'm currently working with (with the embedded `isql` error):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pi() RETURNING DECIMAL;
#                                    ^
#  201: A syntax error has occurred.
#
    DEFINE pi_const DECIMAL;
    LET pi_const = 3.14;
    RETURN pi_const;
END PROCEDURE;
```

I'm not sure what else to try.  I've input examples from IBM's site and from other example/tutorial sites and nothing seems to work.

For reference, I'm using Informix SQL 7.32.UC2 on Informix 11.10.UC1 on AIX 5.3.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596189/cant-create-informix-stored-procedure-using-isql-command?rq=1               Apparently this just plain doesn't work with isql, you have to use dbaccess instead.