# How can I convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, python-2.7, string-formatting

I have the following 24-hour times:

```
{'Wed': '10:30 - 21:00', 'Sun': '10:30 - 21:00', 'Thu': '10:30 - 21:00', 
 'Mon': '10:30 - 21:00', 'Fri': '10:30 - 22:00', 'Tue': '10:30 - 21:00', 
 'Sat': '10:30 - 22:00'}
```

How can I convert this to 12-hour time?

```
{'Wed': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 'Sun': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 
 'Thu': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 'Mon': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 
 'Fri': '10:30 AM- 10:00 PM', 'Tue': '10:30 AM- 09:00 PM', 
 'Sat': '10:30 AM - 10:00 PM'}
```

I want to intelligently convert `"10.30"` to `"10.30 AM"` & `"22:30"` to `"10:30 PM"`. I can do using my own logic but is there a way to do this intelligently without `if`... `elif`?

Comment: Similar but the other way round http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440061/convert-12-hour-date-time-to-24-hour-date-time

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime("10:30", "%H:%M")
>>> d.strftime("%I:%M %p")
'10:30 AM'
>>> d = datetime.strptime("22:30", "%H:%M")
>>> d.strftime("%I:%M %p")
'10:30 PM'
```

Answer (score 17):

The key to this code is to use the [library function `time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the 24-hour string representations into a `time.struct_time` object, then use [library function `time.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to format this `struct_time` into a string of your desired 12-hour format.

I'll assume you have no trouble writing a loop, to iterate through the values in the dict and to break the string into two substrings with one time value each.

For each substring, convert the time value with code like:

```
import time
t = time.strptime(timevalue_24hour, "%H:%M")
timevalue_12hour = time.strftime( "%I:%M %p", t )
```

The question, [*Converting string into datetime*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime), also has helpful answers.

Answer (score 8):

I know many people answer this in a similar way but the more easier way is

```
import time
t = time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
print(t)
```

the `%I` gives the 12 hour clock hour and `%M` minute, `%p` returns the PM or AM value. In my case it returned

```
05:27 PM
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = datetime.strptime("13:30", "%H:%M")
>>> print(s.strftime("%r"))
01:30:00 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import time

# get current time
date_time = time.strftime("%b %d %Y %-I:%M %p")
```

the above outputs: May 27 2020 7:26 PM ...at least for me right now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Python's strftime use %I

reference http://strftime.org/

Comment: this is my favorite. Quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

One may ask, *why add an answer if there are already relevant ones?*
Well, I realized that some questions have been closed without actually getting an accurate solution so I chose to add this solution for OPs who are looking to accomplish same results using only **logic** and **avoiding any `import`**. such as [This OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868520/how-do-you-convert-24-hour-to-12-hour-format-without-using-import-modules)

```py
def convert_time(time_string):
    hours, minutes = map(int, time_string.split(":"))
    meridian = "AM"
    if hours > 12:
        hours -= 12
        meridian = "PM"
    elif hours == 12:
        meridian = "PM"
    elif hours == 0:
        hours = 12
    return f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02} {meridian}"
```

```py
# Call the function:
time_dict = {'Wed': '10:30 - 21:00', 'Sun': '10:30 - 21:00', 'Thu': '10:30 - 21:00', 
 'Mon': '10:30 - 21:00', 'Fri': '10:30 - 22:00', 'Tue': '10:30 - 21:00', 
 'Sat': '10:30 - 22:00'}

for day, hours in time_dict.items():
    start_time, end_time = map(lambda x: x.strip(), hours.split("-"))
    time_dict[day] = f"{convert_time(start_time)} - {convert_time(end_time)}"

print(time_dict)
```

---

```
{'Wed': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 'Sun': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 
'Thu': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 'Mon': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 
'Fri': '10:30 AM - 10:00 PM', 'Tue': '10:30 AM - 09:00 PM', 
'Sat': '10:30 AM - 10:00 PM'}
```

If your time input is a `string` like `"00:29"`, just go ahead and call the function:

```py
str_time_input = "00:29"
print(convert_time(str_time_input)) # 12:29 AM
```

What if you have both hours and minutes as `int`?:

```py
hours = 12
minutes = 17
str_time = f"{hours}:{minutes}"
print(type(str_time))
print(convert_time(str_time))
```

---

```
<class 'str'>
12:17 PM
```