# How to convert AM/PM timestmap into 24hs format in Python?

Tags: python, time, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to convert times from 12 hour times into 24 hour times...

#### Automatic Example times:

```
06:35  ## Morning
11:35  ## Morning (If m2 is anywhere between 10:00 and 12:00 (morning to mid-day) during the times of 10:00 and 13:00 (1pm) then the m2 time is a morning time)
1:35  ## Afternoon
11:35  ## Afternoon
```

#### Example code:

```
m2 = "1:35" ## This is in the afternoon.
m2 = datetime.strptime(m2, "%H:%M")
print m2
```

#### Expected Output:

```
13:35
```

#### Actual Output:

```
1900-01-01 01:35:00
```

---

I tried a second variation but again didn't help :/

```
m2 = "1:35" ## This is in the afternoon.
m2split = m2.split(":")
if len(m2split[0]) == 1:
    m2 = ("""%s%s%s%s""" % ("0", m2split[0], ":", m2split[1]))
    print m2
m2temp = datetime.strptime(m2, "%I:%M")
m2 = m2temp.strftime("%H:%M")
```

---

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855111/convert-24-hours-time-to-12-hours-in-python

Comment: There is nothing in the string `"1:35"` to indicate that it is an afternoon time, so `strptime()` will assume it is morning.  To indicate afternoon, you'd need an am/pm indicator of some sort.

Comment: [SO 13855111](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13855111) is mainly about the converse problem, converting 24 hour to 12 hour time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem is I can't automatically add the PM to the string time? If the m2 value is 10:00 to 12:00 and the real life time is 10:00 to 13:00 (morning to 1pm) then m2 should be considered a morning time, everything else should be considered an afternoon time.

Comment: If you have rules for deciding whether a time is AM or PM, you need to write them in code.  Python can't read your mind.

Comment: @dan04 I just made the said rules to get around this problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :)

#### Code:

```
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M")
if currenttime >= "10:00" and currenttime <= "13:00":
    if m2 >= "10:00" and m2 >= "12:00":
        m2 = ("""%s%s""" % (m2, " AM"))
    else:
        m2 = ("""%s%s""" % (m2, " PM"))
else:
    m2 = ("""%s%s""" % (m2, " PM"))
m2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(m2, '%I:%M %p')
m2 = m2.strftime("%H:%M %p")
m2 = m2[:-3]
print m2
```

#### Output:

```
13:35
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but why are your format strings triple quoted? Also `m2` is a string already, you could just write `m2 += " AM"`. Also you're doing string comparisons in `m2 >= "10:00"`. Why is this answer accepted...

Answer (score 47):

This approach uses strptime and strftime with format directives as per https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior, %H is the 24 hour clock, %I is the 12 hour clock and when using the 12 hour clock, %p qualifies if it is AM or PM.

```
    >>> from datetime import datetime
    >>> m2 = '1:35 PM'
    >>> in_time = datetime.strptime(m2, "%I:%M %p")
    >>> out_time = datetime.strftime(in_time, "%H:%M")
    >>> print(out_time)
    13:35
```

Answer (score 33):

You need to specify that you mean PM instead of AM.

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> m2 = '1:35 PM'
>>> m2 = datetime.strptime(m2, '%I:%M %p')
>>> print(m2)
1900-01-01 13:35:00
```

Comment: Plus, he needs `strftime` to get his desired output.

Comment: @dan04 my strings (m2) are automatically generated elsewhere, I can't add "PM" onto them. I've edited my original post to show some of my times..

Comment: This should be the answer, indeed. Other answers are clones and some others, achieve the result, but using extra computations and resources, unnecessary in comparison to what this proposal is offering.

Answer (score 5):

If date is in this format (HH:MM:SSPM/AM) the following code is effective :

```
a=''
def timeConversion(s):
   if s[-2:] == "AM" :
      if s[:2] == '12':
          a = str('00' + s[2:8])
      else:
          a = s[:-2]
   else:
      if s[:2] == '12':
          a = s[:-2]
      else:
          a = str(int(s[:2]) + 12) + s[2:8]
   return a


s = '11:05:45AM'
result = timeConversion(s)
print(result)
```

Comment: Elegant as an actual algorithm not using much of built-in functions.

Comment: elegant! beautiful!

Answer (score 4):

```
time = raw_input().strip() # input format in hh:mm:ssAM/PM
t_splt = time.split(':')
if t_splt[2][2:] == 'PM' and t_splt[0] != '12':
    t_splt[0] = str(12+ int(t_splt[0]))
elif int(t_splt[0])==12 and t_splt[2][2:] == 'AM':
    t_splt[0] = '00'
t_splt[2] = t_splt[2][:2]
print ':'.join(t_splt)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def timeConversion(s):
    if "PM" in s:
        s=s.replace("PM"," ")
        t= s.split(":")
        if t[0] != '12':
            t[0]=str(int(t[0])+12)
            s= (":").join(t)
        return s
    else:
        s = s.replace("AM"," ")
        t= s.split(":")
        if t[0] == '12':
            t[0]='00'
            s= (":").join(t)
        return s
```

Comment: This is literally the easiest approach. Good one!

Comment: Thank You!, Best one, but just a small change "t[0]" needs to be converted to int in order to compare with 12, int(t[0])

Answer (score 2):

> **Try this**

```
dicti = 
{'01':13,'02':14,'03':15,'04':16,'05':17,'06':18,'07':19,'08':20,'09':21,'10':22,'11':23,'12':12}
s = '12:40:22PM'
if s.endswith('AM'):
if s.startswith('12'):
    s1=s[:8]
    bb=s1.replace('12','00')
    print bb
else:
    s1=s[:8]
    print s1
else:
s1=s[:8]
time= str(s[:2])
ora=str(dicti[time])
aa=s1.replace(time,ora)
print aa
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do this cleanly

`def format_to_24hr(twelve_hour_time):
    return datetime.strftime(
        datetime.strptime(
            twelve_hour_time, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'
        ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "H" for hour indication use "I" as described in the example bellow:

```
from datetime import *
m2 = 'Dec 14 2018 1:07PM'
m2 = datetime.strptime(m2, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
print(m2)
```

Please check this [link](https://onlinecoursetutorials.com/python/how-to-write-a-python-program-to-convert-time-from-12-hour-to-24-hour-format/)

Answer (score 0):

## To convert 12 hour time format into 24 hour time format

''' To check whether time is 'AM' or 'PM' and whether it starts with
12 (noon or morning). In case time is after 12 noon then we add
12 to it, else we let it remain as such. In case time is 12
something in the morning, we convert 12 to (00) '''

def timeConversion(s):

```
    if s[-2:] == 'PM' and s[:2] != '12':
        time = s.strip('PM')
        conv_time = str(int(time[:2])+12)+time[2:]

    elif s[-2:] == 'PM' and s[:2] == '12':
        conv_time = s.strip('PM')

    elif s[-2:] == 'AM' and s[:2] == '12':
        time = s.strip('AM')
        conv_time = '0'+str(int(time[:2])-12)+time[2:]

    else:
        conv_time = s.strip('AM')
        
    return conv_time
```

Comment: It would be helpful is you had a minimum of explanation of what your solution does.

Answer (score 0):

the most basic way is:

```
t_from_str_12h = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%I:%M:%S%p")
str_24h =  t_from_str.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#format HH:MM PM
def convert_to_24_h(hour):
    if "AM" in hour:
        if "12" in hour[:2]:
            return "00" + hour[2:-2]
        return hour[:-2]
    elif "PM" in hour:
        if "12" in hour[:2]:
            return hour[:-2]
    return str(int(hour[:2]) + 12) + hour[2:5]
```

Comment: Use 4 spaces per indentation level. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the manual calculation seems a bit complicated, I am sharing my way of doing it.

```py
# Assumption: Time format (hh:mm am/pm) - You can add seconds as well if you need
def to_24hr(time_in_12hr):
    hr_min, am_pm = time_in_12hr.lower().split()
    hrs, mins = [int(i) for i in hr_min.split(":")]
    hrs %= 12
    hrs += 12 if am_pm == 'pm' else 0
    return f"{hrs}:{mins}"

print(to_24hr('12:00 AM'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# 12-hour to 24-hour time format
import re

s = '12:05:45PM'


def timeConversion(s):
    hour = s.split(':')
    lastString = re.split('(\d+)', hour[2])
    if len(hour[2]) > 2:
        hour[2] = lastString[1]
    if 'AM' not in hour or 'am' not in hour or int(hour[0]) < 12:
        if (lastString.__contains__('PM') and int(hour[0]) < 12) or (lastString.__contains__('pm') and int(hour[0]) < 12):
            hour[0] = str(int(hour[0]) + 12)
    if hour[0] == '12' and (lastString.__contains__('AM') or lastString.count('am')):
        hour[0] = '00'
    x = "{d}:{m}:{y}".format(d=hour[0], m=hour[1], y=hour[2])
    return x


print(timeConversion(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution by using python builtin functions to convert **12-hour time format into 24-hour time format**

```py
def time_conversion(s):
    if s.endswith('AM') and s.startswith('12'):
        s = s.replace('12', '00')
    if s.endswith('PM') and not s.startswith('12'):
        time_s = s.split(':')
        time_s[0] = str(int(time_s[0]) + 12)
        s = ":".join(time_s)
        
    s = s.replace('AM', '').replace('PM', '')
    
    return s
```

```py
time_conversion('07:05:45PM') 

19:05:45
```

Comment: I would reccomand             time_s[0] = '%02d'%(int(time_s[0]) + 12)

Answer (score 0):

### We can consider 12 and 24 as numeral systems

with bases of 12 and 24, respectively.
In this context, AM/PM serves as the value 0 or 1 in the second place of the numeral system with a base of 12.

### For example:

| Hours | base 12 | base 24 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3AM | 03 | 03 |
| 3PM | 13 | 0d |
| 11PM | 1b | 0n |

To convert from the base-12 system to the base-24 system, the following function will be helpful.

```
def timeConversion(s):
    second_order = {
        "PM": 1,
        "AM": 0
    }
    hours, rest_time, ampm = s[:2], s[2:-2], s[-2:]
    result_hour = second_order[ampm] * 12 + int(hours) % 12
    return f'{result_hour:02d}{rest_time}'
```

Answer (score -1):

`%H`    Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%I`    Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

```
m2 = "1:35" ## This is in the afternoon.
m2 = datetime.strptime(m2, "<b>%I</b>:%M")
print(m2)
```

Comment: %H Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. <br>
%I Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

m2 = "1:35" ## This is in the afternoon. 

m2 = datetime.strptime(m2, "%I:%M") 
print(m2)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.