# Python: converting a string containing a 12-hr time format to its military time

Tags: python, string, time

Coding in Python

I have a CSV file with a column called `time` that consists of strings like `12:00:00 AM` and `10:00:00 PM`. I simply want to convert these strings into their corresponding military time representation either by string or integer such that `12:00:00 AM` becomes `"0"` or `0` and `10:00:00 PM` becomes `"22"` or `22`.

I am new to coding in general so I have no idea what are the correct keywords to search for. Thanks!

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Questions looking for offsite resources are offtopic, but you can start to read here: [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) or simply search SO with "python parse time" f.e starting to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime/466376#466376)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 12 hour into 24 hour times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229190/convert-12-hour-into-24-hour-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try coding it first by yourself and update your question by posting your code when you encounter errors with it.

To give you a head start, you can start by reading the [time module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) of python. In particular, you will be needing the `time.strptime` to convert your `string format` to a `time format` then output your desired `military time format` using `time.strftime`.

Make sure to check out the directives properly for the formatting of your strings. Happy coding!

Comment: Just to add, you may use [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/137906/revisions) as a reference while you code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

t = '12:00:00 AM'

t_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M:%S %p')
```

then you can access the hour with `t_dt.hour`