# convert 24 hour time (in string format) to time format

Tags: python

The time is given in string for eg "23:20". However in my function I need to compare times for which I gotta convert these to time format

I tried strptime() and it works with 12 hour format for eg when I enter "12:00PM"

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please show a code attempt and what you passed into `strptime`. There are a couple different things to consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting 24 hour format to a `datetime.time` object you need to use the `%H` (hours in 24h format) and `%M` (minutes) format:

```py
import datetime as dt

string_time = "23:20"
out_time = dt.datetime.strptime(string_time, r"%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229190/how-to-convert-am-pm-timestmap-into-24hs-format-in-python]

Code that works from there

%H is the 24 hour clock, %I is the 12 hour clock and when using the 12 hour clock, %p qualifies if it is AM or PM.

```py
   from datetime import datetime
   m2 = '1:35 PM'
   in_time = datetime.strptime(m2, "%I:%M %p")
   out_time = datetime.strftime(in_time, "%H:%M")
   print(out_time)
   13:35
```

Comment: my input is in 24 hour string format

Comment: Then I believe just do the reverse (in_time - out_time