# Date time format conversion in python

Tags: python, date, python-2.6

I have a string containing time stamp in format

> (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM), e.g."12/20/2014 15:25:05 pm"

. 
The time here is in 24 Hrs format.

I need to convert into same format but with time in 12-Hrs format.

I am using python version 2.6.

I have gone through time library of python but couldn't come up with any solution.

Comment: related: [Convert 24 hours time to 12 hours in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13855111/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View Live **[ideOne](http://ideone.com/mV7otU)** use [**Python `datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime),

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> date_str='12/20/2014 15:25:05 pm'

>>> date_obj = dt.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

>>> dt.strftime(date_obj, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
'12/20/2014 03:25:05 PM'
```

Comment: Hello @J.F.Sebastian thank you for informing, I missed to add `from datetime` that why not worked, now worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to convert your Input date string to Python datetime object and then convert it back to date string

```
import datetime

#Input Date String
t = "12/20/2014 15:25:05 pm"

#Return a datetime corresponding to date string
dateTimeObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
print dateTimeObject
```

**Output:** 2014-12-20 15:25:05

```
#Return a string representing the date
dateTimeString = datetime.datetime.strftime(dateTimeObject, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print dateTimeString
```

**Output:** 12/20/2014 03:25:05 PM

Answer (score 1):

After creating a datetime object using `strptime` you then call `strftime` and pass the desired format as a string see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
In [162]:

t = "12/20/2014 15:25:05 pm"
dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'), '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
Out[162]:
'12/20/2014 03:25:05 PM'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Shortest & simplest solution --

I really appreciate & admire (coz I barely manage to read man pages :P) you going through time documentation, but why use "astonishing" & "cryptic" code when simple code could get the job done

Just extract the hour part as  int & replace it by `hrs-12` if it is greater than 12

```
t = "12/20/2014 15:25:05 pm"

hrs = int( t.split()[1][:2] )

if hrs > 12:
    t = t.replace( str(hrs), str(hrs-12) )
```

### Output

See explaination & live output [here](http://ideone.com/cfkGGd)

### Using Lambda

If you like one liners, checkout `f()` below

```
t = "12/20/2014 15:25:05 pm"

f = lambda tym: tym.replace(str(int(tym.split()[1][:2])), str(int(tym.split()[1][:2])-12)) if int(tym.split()[1][:2]) > 12 else tym

print(f(t))
```