# Clock in python using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to make a clock that shows the date and time in 12-hour but I don't know how to switch it from 24-hour. I used datetime.datetime.now but its in 24-hour.

```py
while True:
    from datetime import datetime, timezone
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
    x=datetime.now(ZoneInfo('US/Eastern'))
    if x>12:
        print(x, 'pm')
    else:
        print(x, 'am')
```

I tried that but it said that it wouldn't work because datetime cant be int

Sorry the title is short by the way it kept giving me a message and only this worked.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.. SO is not a code writing service.... We will help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855111/how-can-i-convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time)

Comment: Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855111/how-can-i-convert-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time

Comment: You might want to have a look at the difference between a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and the string representation of such an object. You can get a 12h-clock *format* with the appropriate [formatting directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), `%I`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `hour > 12`, if True, print 'pm', otherwise 'am'. Print hours number like that : `hour % 12` (you can put an exception with a if statement for 12am/pm to keep 12 instead of 00).

Comment: Although the idea of the answer is correct, it would vastly be improved if a code snippet is added demonstrating the fix. This way, future users have a reference to what the actual issue is.