# Sort by 12-hour time?

Tags: bash, sorting, time

quick (and probably stupid) question this morning:

I have data being fed to my script that looks like this:

```
03:00P - Doctor appointment.
07:00P - Scheduled entry.
10:30A - Another entry.
11:00A - Daytime medication is due.
11:00P - Nighttime medication is due.
11:30P - Staff meeting.
```

Now I can't change the source of the data, and the output needs to look the same, but I need to sort it properly. Any ideas on fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You manage to avoid the interesting times: `12:05A - Just past midnight and long before 11:00A` and `12:05P - Just past midday and long before 11:00P`.  The accepted answer does not handle those times correctly.

Comment: You might find the information in [Convert 12-hour date/time to 24-hour date/time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440061/convert-12-hour-date-time-to-24-hour-date-time/440110#440110) useful in dealing with the issue.  I think you're likely to find that preprocessing with Perl or Awk or Python to add a column containing the AM/PM time converted into 24-hour notation, then sorting on the 24-hour column, and then (if necessary) removing it is likely to be 'best', unless there's a built-in option to `sort` to handle AM/PM time sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell sort to first sort on the sixth character, then on the first to fifth:

```
sort -k1.6,1.6 -k1.1,1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the `A` or `P` from the time and place it it front of the time, it sorts correctly just using the normal `sort` command.  So maybe something like this:

```
awk '{print substr($1,6), $0}' < input  | sort | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

The `awk` command generates output like this:

```
P 03:00P - Doctor appointment.
P 07:00P - Scheduled entry.
A 10:30A - Another entry.
A 11:00A - Daytime medication is due.
P 11:00P - Nighttime medication is due.
P 11:30P - Staff meeting.
```

Which we then `sort`, and then strip the prefix.

Comment: Eh, I like @choroba's solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on a simple Perl script derived from the answer to [Convert 12-hour date/time to 24-hour date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440061/convert-12-hour-date-time-to-24-hour-date-time/440110#440110).

#### Source `s12.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub time_12h_to_24h
{
    my($t12) = @_;
    my($hh,$mm,$ampm) = $t12 =~ m/^(\d\d?):(\d\d?)\s*([AP]M?)/i;
    $hh = ($hh % 12) + (($ampm =~ m/AM?/i) ? 0 : 12);
    return sprintf("%.2d:%.2d", $hh, $mm);
}

while (<>)
{
    my($time_12h, $entry) = split / - /;
    my $time_24h = time_12h_to_24h($time_12h);
    print "$time_24h $time_12h - $entry";
}
```

Note that the code accepts both { `AM`, `PM` } and { `A`, `P` } and is neutral between upper-case and lower-case for the AM/PM indicator, and ignores spaces between the time and AM/PM indicator.

#### Input data

This data sets contains rows for 12:05A and 12:05P as well as the data from the question.

```
03:00P - Doctor appointment.
07:00P - Scheduled entry.
10:30A - Another entry.
11:00A - Daytime medication is due.
11:00P - Nighttime medication is due.
11:30P - Staff meeting.
12:05A - Just past midnight and long before 11:00A.
12:05P - Just past midday and long before 11:00P.
```

#### Double-filtered output

```
$ perl s12.pl data | sort | sed 's/^..:.. //'
12:05A - Just past midnight and long before 11:00A.
10:30A - Another entry.
11:00A - Daytime medication is due.
12:05P - Just past midday and long before 11:00P.
03:00P - Doctor appointment.
07:00P - Scheduled entry.
11:00P - Nighttime medication is due.
11:30P - Staff meeting.
$
```

#### Unfiltered output

```
$ perl s12.pl data | sort
00:05 12:05A - Just past midnight and long before 11:00A.
10:30 10:30A - Another entry.
11:00 11:00A - Daytime medication is due.
12:05 12:05P - Just past midday and long before 11:00P.
15:00 03:00P - Doctor appointment.
19:00 07:00P - Scheduled entry.
23:00 11:00P - Nighttime medication is due.
23:30 11:30P - Staff meeting.
$
```

Note that by placing the key column (24 hour time column) first in the output, the `sort` command is simplified (and, in general, it speeds up the sort too).