# How to convert 12hrs to 24hrs in python

Tags: python, converters

I try to convert 12 hrs time format to 24hrs time format. I expected output like this:

> 2020-12-31 17:59:59.

No need of extra *-06:00. Can some suggest on this?

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser as dparser
date_str='December 31, 2020 5:59:59 PM CST'
date=dparser.parse(date_str)
print 'date =',date
```

**output of script**

> date = 2020-12-31 17:59:59-06:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 12-hour date/time to 24-hour date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440061/convert-12-hour-date-time-to-24-hour-date-time)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the timezone tag

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser as dparser
date_str='December 31, 2020 5:59:59 PM'
date=dparser.parse(date_str)
print 'date =',date,'CST'
```

**Output**

> date = 2020-12-31 17:59:59 CST

Comment: I need timezone tag as well.

Comment: Just add CST to the end. `print 'date =',date,'CST'`